# To cancle any api request Using Alamofire in swift

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am calling api using alamofire in swift.it is a search api, when I am searching any text in searchbar I am calling the api. I am calling the api after a delay of 0.75 seconds. I want to cancel the previous request, when new request is there. But I don’t know how to cancel the request. Can anyone help me?

```
 func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(self.reload(_:)), object: searchBar)
        perform(#selector(self.reload(_:)), with: searchBar, afterDelay: 0.75)
    }



  @objc func reload(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
     
        guard let query = searchBar.text, query.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) != "" else {
            self.searchLcodeWithText("")
            
            print("nothing to search")
            return
        }
        self.searchLcodeWithText(query)
        
        print(query)
    }

 private func searchLcodeWithText(_ newText: String){
        //Show
        startActivityIndicator()
        apiService.searchlcode(searchText: newText) { [self] (lcodeData) in
            allLcodeArray = []
            //Hide
            if let lcde = lcodeData{
               
                if lcde.count > 0{
              
                    allLcodeArray.append(contentsOf: lcde)
                    stopActivityIndicator()
                }
              
            }
            else{
               
            }
            stopActivityIndicator()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

class ApiService{

  func searchlcode(searchText: String, completion: @escaping searchLcodeTypeAliasCompletion){
        
        guard let urlrequest = URL(string: SEARCH_URL) else {return}
        var parameters = [String:Any]()
        parameters.updateValue(searchText, forKey: "lcode_name")
        Alamofire.request(urlrequest, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { [self] (response : DataResponse<Any>) in
            if let error = response.result.error {
                debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }else{
            
            guard let data = response.data else { return completion(nil)}
            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            do {
                
                let searchUser = try jsonDecoder.decode(searchLcodeTypeAlias.self, from: data)
                print(searchUser)
                completion(searchUser)
            } catch {
                debugPrint(error)
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: You can probably use Operation and OperationQueu

Answer (score 0):

```
 Return DataRequest in function  then you can cancel specific request. 

for Example. 
 
    @discardableResult
        func login(params: loginRequestModel, completion: @escaping (RequestResult<UserDataResponse, String>) -> Void) -> DataRequest {
            
            params.printJson()
            let url = baseUrl + endPoints.login.rawValue
            let request = sessionManager.request(url,method: .post, parameters: params, headers: headers)
            
            request.responseDecodable(of: UserDataResponse.self){ (response) in
                completion(self.getValidResponse(response))
            }
            
           
            return request
        }
```

usage in viewController
step1 declaration: var loginDataRequest: DataRequest?

step2: initialise data request in function call

step3: action event cancel this request
loginDataRequest.cancel

another  approach
you can achieve by using dispatch work Item or operation Queue